# Ubuntu crashes when clicking indicator menu

Tags: 16.04, unity, indicator, crash

Every time i click the engine/power button in the indicator menu (for powering or suspending purposes) my system crashes.
This happens every time i start a new session and i click the indicator for the first time. After crashing and presenting me a sorry/send report window, if i click the indicator again it works fine.
Before crashing, i can notice that X tries to render the boundaries of the list that should appear. The area flashes transparent for ~2s and then fade very quick, and the crash window shows up.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I couldn't find any topic with a similar issue.
I'm very new to the OS and don't even know how to open the crash file in /var/crash to provide more information.

**Crash title says:**

`unity-panel-service crashed with SIGSEGV in g_hasg_table_foreach()`

Any help in fixing this will be appreciated.